# Hibernate Envers: I'm getting nulls in a List when loading a revision

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-envers

I have an object "Foo" that contains a list of other objects "Bar".  If I load up a revision of Foo, I get my correctly ordered list of Bars - however I also get a number of nulls.  If I look at the audit table that holds the bars I see something like this on the initial object save:

```
    id   | rev  | revtype |    create_timestamp     |    update_timestamp     | updated_by_id | created_by_id | foo_id                | bar_index     | bar_value
   ------+------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------------+---------------+-----------
    1000 | 1000 |       0 | 2018-09-28 12:26:48.49  | 2018-09-28 12:26:48.49  |             1 |             1 |                       |               | ValueA    
    1001 | 1000 |       0 | 2018-09-28 12:26:48.49  | 2018-09-28 12:26:48.49  |             1 |             1 |                       |               | ValueB    
    1000 | 1000 |       0 |                         |                         |               |               |                  1000 |             0 |           
    1001 | 1000 |       0 |                         |                         |               |               |                  1000 |             1 |
```

So then in the future I want to grab Foo which has Revision 1000 for the Bars I end up with 2 nulls and my two values.  Seeing that table I'm not totally surprised.  If feels like a bug with how Lists are processed, if I change it to a set it works fine (So I guess I could leave it as a set, then populate the index column myself and sort it myself when loaded - but that isn't great for an object hierarchy and a lot of lists) But I could just be missing something in how I'm doing things.

Mapping in Bar:

```
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "foo_id")
    @OrderColumn(name = "bar_index")
    private List<Bar> bars = new ArrayList<>();
```

Any thoughts on how to make this work without getting nulls in the loaded list?  Is it an Envers bug, Hibernate bug, user error?  Thanks!

Comment: Couple questions: What version if Hibernate & Envers are you using?  Secondly, does your `Bar` entity properly implement an `equals` and `hashCode` method?  If so, could you update the post with it.

Comment: 5.2.17 for both.  Equals is generated via lombok and includes a super.equals which is the baseentity (id, version, createdByUser, updatedByUser, createdTime, updatedTiem) the rest of it is generic field checkers.

Comment: Couple final questions: How is the create/update user_id and timestamps being populated?  It looks like you may have some type of callback or listener which is modifying the collection elements at a point where it shouldn't and due to your equals/hashcode implementations, its causing duplicates.  Can you explain those fields?

Comment: Sure, create/update user_id is currently not implemented so is hardcoded to 1 inside the object (I.e, Long updateId = 1L;) update/create timestamp are Instants with a default Instant.now() but also annotated with @CreatedDate/LastModifiedDate though it looks like there are no entitylisteners or @prepersist/@preupdate  so not sure if we have any code for those, doesn't seem like we modify the collection as part of the save process anywhere.  Also if I switch everything to a set everything is fine (other than no order, ha) but that does seem to imply something about how the list code works.

Comment: Please change your equals/hashcode logic to exclude the user_id/timestamp fields and see whether or not things work as intended.  I really suspect that's likely the culprit.  You have to be super careful with equals/hashcode.

Comment: Ok I changed to have equals/hashcode just use the id, same issue.  But more interesting, looking at the hibernate statements it creates the Bar rows, then goes and updates them to set the bar_index and foo_id.  So since it is auditing changes, it saves both changes on the same revision (but in different rows for some reason?) I would expect to just see the final result in the audit table for what is presumably a single transaction (vs the save/update rows I see now) Am I crazy?   Still feel like something is wrong, though I can pull the revision and get the proper order - just with extra nulls

Comment: That sounds like a bug; I would open a jira with a reproducable test case and I can take a look as to why that is happening.

Comment: Sure, where should I file it?

Comment: You can report it at https://hibernate.atlassian.net.

Comment: Thanks.  In the process of making the example (which I have and does reproduce) I think I worked out the issue, which is maybe more of a skipping an error message.  I'll answer the question and you can tell me if I should file a bug report for my suspected missing error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think is happening (and how to fix.)  The above is a unidirectional OneToMany relationship that does not use a join table.  So you only have FOO and BAR tables.

In my case I happened to name them FOO and FOO_BAR (with associated _AUD tables)

However Envers requires an additional audit join table in this situation (for various good reasons) and enforces that there is a join table named ONE_MANY_AUD, so in this case it seems like it would expect FOO, FOO_AUD, BAR, BAR_AUD, FOO_BAR_AUD  and it enforces the audit join table exists as it expects.

I only had FOO, FOO_AUD, FOO_BAR and FOO_BAR_AUD which Envers was fine with because it seems to match it's expected join table naming, but causes the problem described in the question.

I'm not exactly sure what Envers does in that situation, it seems like maybe it is trying to put the audits for Bar and the Foo-Bar relationship into the same table.

Too fix I could make my Bar table actually be called BAR (with BAR_AUD) and add the expected audit join table FOO_BAR_AUD.  At which point things work as expected and I don't end up with nulls in the list of BARs when retrieving revisions of FOO.

It would be nice to update the checks in Envers to catch that situation if that is possible (and I'm successfully guessing what is going on!)